# How can I determine the total possible distributions of a sequence if order matters, but repeated numbers don't?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I have 5 different digits, 0 to 4, being distributed into 64 spaces.
I'm starting with:

0123401234012340123401234012340123401234012340123401234012340123

*edit*  I failed to mention that I'm starting with the seed number above and rearranging them on digit at a time using Heap's algorithm.  I have to use the numbers above and not just any set of numbers.  So all 0s is out.

Order does matter, but only distinct distributions are counted.
So, if we were working with only 6 digits:
012340 is the same as 012340 (When technically the two 0s were swapped.) so we would discard the second number there.

How can I determine how many distinct arrangements there are?  I have a C# application crunching the numbers for me and so far it's found 64,000 distinct number arrangements (After 24 hours).  I'm trying to figure out if I'm close to being done, or if it's barely gotten started.

When I ran the code on only 6 digits, it found 360 distinct numbers out of 720 possible arrangements.  8 digits found 5040 distinct out of 40320 possible arrangements.  Clearly there's a formula here, but I'm unable to see it.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the number of times each digit is used?  Could we have $64$ zeros, for example?

Comment: This is not clear.  Why isn't the answer $5^{64}$? Maybe it would help to show, explicitly, what the answer is for a shorter string.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I didn't explain that correctly.  I'm starting with the seed number above and rearranging those numbers using Heap's algorithm.

Comment: No idea what that means.  Can you edit your question for clarity and completeness?

Comment: I edited the post.  I'm starting with the seed number above and switching each number one at a time until I get all possible permutations.  I have to use that string of numbers and only rearrange them.

Comment: What difference does it make what algorithm you are using?  Are you looking for the number of distinct rearrangements of that list or does the algorithm omit some?

Comment: If you just want the number of ways to rearrange those characters, note that there are $13$ of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $12$ of $\{4\}$.  So the answer is $\binom {64}{13}\times \binom {51}{13}\times \binom {38}{13}\times \binom {25}{13}$

Comment: The program will not list all permutations during your lifetime.  There are $$176180836511001764739212088155077616640000$$ of them